# how can i get exact leftover time of a media element?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-player

How can I get the exact amount of time left before an audio or video element finishes?

If I try `element.duration-element.currentTime`, it gives me a value that's one or two microseconds off(half the time), and it adds a weird 999999 or 99998 at the end.

Is there a way to do that the two microseconds faster, or a value that can get that?

Comment: Are you adamant on using ms as unit of measurement? Also, is the purpose of this to show the end user the remaining time, or to detect when the video finishes?

Comment: @KennethLew, both `currentTime` and `duration` are measured in seconds. the purpose is to show the end user the remaning time (assuming "detect when the video finishes" is just true or false).
but im done with this already. i looked it up and found out that this is hopeless. its how javascript is horrible with decimals.